# no module named error python, is it on sys.path?

Tags: python, django

Okay, I am getting an error that is like no module named credentials

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3qQo.png

I have a credentials.py file in that directory. I am sort of new to python and this is driving me nuts.

How can I debug this, or can anyone tell right off the bat what may be the problem?

Comment: Next time, please copy and paste your terminal instead of posting a screenshot : )

Comment: okay! sorry! it is in a virtual-env and I rarely use the virtualenv browser because logging in again. ha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `python keep_backend/manage.py runserver`, then your `PYTHONPATH` will not include the current directory. Instead, in will include the `keep_backend` directory.

Since `credentials.py` is in the current directory, it is not importable.

---

A workaround is manually adding the right folder to your `PYTHONPATH`

```
PYTHONPATH=`pwd`:$PYTHONPATH python keep_backend/manage.py runserver
```

But you should most likely rethink your directory structure here.

Comment: Thank you! I am closer to figuring this out :D!
apparently I have to use this!
http://www.miniwebtool.com/django-secret-key-generator/

Any tips on how I can get it to work (now that I have it recognizing the credential file)

Comment: @user2783087 Relying a web tool you don't control to generate security parameters seems like a bad idea. Generate it using your computer's entropy instead: `import random; print ''.join([random.SystemRandom().choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*(-_=+)') for i in range(50)])`